# Is there a way to programmatically read the contents of a subtitle text stream embedded in an mkv file without extracting the track altogether?

Tags: video, python, video-conversion

Extracting a subtitle track from an mkv would take a bit of a long time, well over a few minutes in the case of huge video filesizes (>10GB), and I think analyzing the text contents of a subtitle stream would be beneficial to figuring out if I want to extract it or not.

A video player is able to seemingly read the entire contents of a subtitle stream from the getgo, so I assume there is a way.

Comment: What is the difference between “reading” and “extracting”?

Comment: @szatmary Extracting the track takes a long time. A video player is able to read the entire text stream as soon as the video file is loaded, so it must be doing something different than extracting and then reading

Comment: “A video player is able to seemingly read the entire contents of a subtitle stream from the getgo,” <- this is your faulty assumption. A video player is not magic. So either the player has a separate file (like an srt) or there is something wrong with how you “extract”

Comment: the subtitle is embedded into the mkv file. I use mkvmerge to extract the subtitle file. With a 10GB mkv file, it takes upwards of 4-5 minutes to extract the subtitle track from the mkv with mkvmerge.

Comment: mkvmerge must be doing more that just reading the subtitles. Or you have a slow hard drive. BTW, how do you know the player has ALL the sub titles when it starts to render, and it not reading them just in time to display?

Comment: I tested it by adding a subtitle line at the very end of an SRT file, wrote the timestamp as '00:00:00,500 --> 00:00:02,000'  and re-muxed it back into the mkv file using mkvtoolnix. The video player displayed the subtitle just fine. This was a 3-hour long 15GB video

Comment: I’m not sure what that proves except the SRT parser can reorder entries before writing them to the file.